# Buscar dados em Json e exibir tempo em tempo e passar para o javascrtipt

Tags: php, ajax, json

Preciso pegar os dados que estão em formato json exemplo:

```
{"latitude": "-3,3462, -60,6790"}
```

Preciso exibir os resultado tempo em tempo tipo a cada 5 segundos e passar para o javascript sem dar refresh na página.

> javascript

```js
var testMarker = L.marker([-3.3462, -60.6790],{icon: orangeIcon}).bindPopup('Kedson<br>Visto: 12:00pm');
```

Comment: o exibir que você refere é retornar para um websocket, ou ajax, ou você esta usando CLI e precisa ficar verificando uma variável em alguma thread?

Comment: No javascript esta assim: var testMarker = L.marker([-3.3462, -60.6790],{icon: orangeIcon}).bindPopup('Kedson<br>Visto: 12:00pm');

Comment: Preciso alterar esses valores -3.3462, -60.6790 a cada 5 segundos que e a latitude

Comment: Então você tem uma variável no javascript que precisa que a cada 5 segundos seja atualizado com o valor mais recente do serviço em php, isso? está usando algum framework no javascript ou no php?

Comment: Vou colocar o codigo javascript abaixo da pergunta

Comment: Esse objeto que você colocou das coordenadas é assim mesmo? Com o valor da latitude e longitude com virgula no separador decimal e ainda separados por vírgula, tudo dentro de uma string? Não pode retornar do PHP algo do tipo `{"latitude": -3.346, "longitude": -60.6790}` ou `{"coord": [-3.3462, -60.6790]}` ?

Comment: {"latitude": -3.346, "longitude": -60.6790}

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma consulta ajax que ao final da consulta ele lança um setTimeout com o tempo para a próxima atualização, o código com jquery ficaria algo assim :

```
function updateData(){
  $.post( "/echo/json/",{}, function( data ) {
    /* Atualiza os dados */
    setTimeout(updateData,5000);
  });
}
updateData();
```

Comment: No caso a pagina se atualizar sozinho ?

Comment: Isso, depois que chamou a função na primeira vez, ela vai se chamar a cada 5 segundos

Answer (score 0):

### Usando o [`$.getJSON`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp) do jQuery

Você pode usar um código semelhante a esse em que você coloca um timer para atualizar a cada 5 segundos, que vai buscar um JSON via ajax e atualiza algo via JS quando retornar.

```
setInterval( function () {
  $.getJSON("endereco_da_pagina_com_coordendas.php", function (data) {
      // codigo para atualizar o JS, exemplo:
      // se o JSON que retornar do PHP for '{coordenadas: [x, y]}'
      var testMarker = L.marker(data.coordenadas, {icon: orangeIcon}).bindPopup('Kedson<br>Visto: 12:00pm'); 
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: creio que seja o setInterval, o setTimeout vai rodar apenas uma vez, e ele precisa que seja atualizado a cada 5 segundos

Comment: No caso a pagina se atualizar sozinho ?

Comment: creio que seja isso que ele queira, que o valor se atualize de 5 em 5 segundos

Comment: @Antonio tem razão. vou atualizar a resposta.